# Recent content missing on old API

Tags: youtube-api

We have been using this url to get the new published videos: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=clubhauseighties

We noticed 2 new videos weren't appearing. One is 4 days old!

After research I found out that using: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?orderby=published&author=clubhauseighties
one of the 2 new videos appear, not the latest.

Using instead: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/clubhauseighties/uploads?v=2
they all appear, but this breaks our parsing.

Any idea why this difference and if there is a way to get the latest content without having to change the parser from my side?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Isn't this a question for youtube? Have you looked on the youtube API site or forums. Its it possible that the one feed missing videos is an error that they need to fix? I'm not sure this a good question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is the official place to get support from the YouTube API team.

Answer (score 0):

The first two queries are using the V1 data API - which is now deprecated. You should rewrite the application to use either the V2 data API, or the (currently experimental) V3 data api.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v1_deprecation_notice